# Code example for Sentiment Analysis for Asian languages - Python NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis, asianfonts

There is a demo on `sentiment analysis` with `NLTK` (python) here http://text-processing.com/demo/sentiment/.

And also the tutorials on the parts of sentiment analysis

- http://streamhacker.com/2010/06/16/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-eliminate-low-information-features/
- http://streamhacker.com/2010/05/10/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-naive-bayes-classifier/
- http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch07.html

**Is there any full code example or working projects with python NLTK on sentiment analysis for *Asian languages*?** (especially for Chinese, Japanese, Korean or Arabic, Hebrew and Persian languages)

Comment: hi, did you find a solution for this problem to support many languages?

Answer (score 1):

In the Japanese version of *Natural Language Processing with Python* there is an extra-chapter dedicated to Japanese processing: https://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book-jp/ch12.html (in Japanese).

Unless you're looking for symbolic approaches to sentiment analysis, you can apply existing technics to Japanese (or whatever language you want to process) and use language specific tools for the preprocessing step.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any examples using NLTK, but the [chatterbox](https://www.mashape.com/chatterbox-co/chinese-sentiment-analysis-for-social-media) (social media oreinted) and [chinese-analytics](https://www.mashape.com/soshio/chinese-analytics) (business oriented) libraries can be used to perform sentiment analysis for Chinese languages.